# If statement not working properly while data gets inserted

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I have created a function which takes three parameters.
My function is simple, it connects to database using pdo but when I call it the data gets inserted, but when I wrap the function inside variable, the if statement doesn't work as expected. My function is just like this

```
function connect($data,$username,$password){
    try { $connect =new PDO($data,$username,$password);
    $connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $connect->exec("INSERT INTO data(fname,lname,uname, password) VALUES('raashid','din','dar','wow')");
    } catch( Exception $e) {
        echo "error occurred". $e->get messages();
    }
    return;
}

$db =connect("mysql:host=localhost","root","pass");
if($db){
    echo "Yes connected";
} else {
    echo " not connected";
}
```

I don't know why if conditional shows not connected while data gets inserted.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You are missing a `"` from then end of your `exec` function.

Comment: Why a `catch` block without a `try` ?? Makes no sense

Comment: Total typo mess: Missing `"` on query means the script wont compile or run

Comment: I see the edit. But is that the real code you are running?

Comment: Yes I edited the code it is the same code I am running it. The data gets inserted but if statement not working

Comment: I see your newest edit. Please remember when asking a question. If you show us code we assume that is what you are running. If you miss **important** bits out, that is what people will see and what they will assume are the errors. **That wastes your time AND ours**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Empty `return;` is the same as `return null;`. And null is considered `falsy` value, so `if($db){` is `false` and you see the relevant message.

So, you should return another value from your function. For example `true` when everything is ok and `false` when exception occured, for example:

```
function connect($data,$username,$password){
    try {
        $connect = new PDO($data,$username,$password);
        $connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $connect->exec("INSERT INTO data(fname,lname,uname, password) VALUES('raashid','din','dar','wow')");
        return true;
    } catch( Exception $e) {
        echo "error occurred". $e->getMessage();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Might be worth mentioning the missing `"` which means the script wont actually compile

Comment: Show what? How to write `return true;`?

Comment: And the total lack of a `TRY` block to match the `CATCH` block

Comment: _I think you are about to disappear down the_ ___Rabbit Hole___ @u_mulder

Comment: @RiggsFolly probably)

Comment: Rabbit hole means, also I am learning functions like how they work, and how they work inside variable when called. So it for learning purpose.